# Vue.js – how to clone element with events?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, dom-events

I have a Vue.js plugin where user can transmit they elements as slot. I have to clone some of them (in specific situations). Of course, users can add events to these elements. For example:

```
<component>
    <div class="slot-item" @click="myMethod(1)"></div>
    <div class="slot-item" @click="myMethod(2)"></div>
    <div class="slot-item" @click="myMethod(3)"></div>
</component>
```

How to clone this slot elements with all Vue/JS events? And finally have rendered HTML, for example:

```
<div class="my-component">
    <!-- It's the last item cloned -->
    <div class="slot-item cloned-slot-item" @click="myMethod(3)"></div>

    <!-- These are the original user elements -->
    <div class="slot-item" @click="myMethod(1)"></div>
    <div class="slot-item" @click="myMethod(2)"></div>
    <div class="slot-item" @click="myMethod(3)"></div>

    <!-- It's the first item cloned --> 
    <div class="slot-item cloned-slot-item" @click="myMethod(1)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean _"...clone this slot elements..."_ ?

Comment: I edited the question. I hope it is now clearer.

Comment: Is `component` the `component` element from vue, or a placeholder for your component?

Comment: @Ferrybig It's my vue component that I'm creating. Of course, it has a different name, but I didn't want to go into details.

Answer (score 0):

What you can use is using a separate slots for the first and last parts of the context.

This can be used as follows:

```js
Vue.component('example-component', {
  template: '#example-component',
});

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  template: '#example-app',
  methods: {
    log(m, classTest) {
      console.log(m, classTest);
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>



<script type="text/x-template" id="example-component">
    <div>
        <slot name="last" className="clone"></slot>
        <slot name="first"></slot>
        <slot></slot>
        <slot name="last"></slot>
        <slot name="first" className="clone"></slot>
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="example-app">
    <example-component>
        <template slot="first" slot-scope="props">
            <div @click="log('first: ', props.className)" :class="props.className">
                first
            </div>
        </template>
        <div @click="log('middle1')">
            middle1
        </div>
        <div @click="log('middle2')">
            middle2
        </div>
        <template slot="last" slot-scope="props">
            <div @click="log('last: ', props.className)" :class="props.className">
                last
            </div>
        </template>
    </example-component>
</script>
<div id="demo">
</div>
```